# Is is possible javascript function to return new DOM element but created with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:

```
function getNewElement(elementName, elementClass) {
    return $('<p>')
        .addClass(elementClass)
        .text(elementName);
}
```

And then i can reuse it like:

```
const paragraph = getNewElement('test', 'some-class');
const paragraphSecond = getNewElement('test2', 'some-class2');
```

Is there any way to run the code or any similar approach ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 0th item in a jQuery object is the native DOM Element object. As such just add `[0]` to the `return` statement in your function to get your desired output:

```js
function getNewElement(elementName, elementClass) {
  return $('<p>').addClass(elementClass).text(elementName)[0];
}

const paragraph = getNewElement('test', 'some-class');
console.dir(paragraph);

const paragraphSecond = getNewElement('test2', 'some-class2');
console.dir(paragraphSecond);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That being said, there's nothing inherently wrong with returning a jQuery object from the function which will stop it from being re-used. Any problem would only come from how you use the *result* of the function in later logic.

Answer (score 1):

you could create the element using the following approach:

```js
function getNewElement(elementName, elementClass) {
    return $(document.createElement("p"))
        .addClass(elementClass)
        .text(elementName)
        .get(0);
}
```

Comment: oh sorry, I misread the title.. I have updated with the correct code

Comment: `$(document.createElement("p"))` seems superfluous

Answer (score 0):

The function below generates a tag and returns it:

```js
function getNewElement(elementName, elementClass, tagName = "p") {
  return $('<'+tagName+'>').addClass(elementClass).text(elementName)[0];
}
```

Comment: Note that in the case of the OP this would return a `<test>` or `<test2>` element, not a `<p>` element